# What is the value of $1.5 \choose 0 $?

Tags: combinatorics

I checked falling factorials but I am not sure what happens when $k=0$ here. Is it possible to compute, or is it simply $0$ ?

Comment: Depends what you mean.  I think the most common answer would be to use the Gamma function to extend the definition of the binomial coefficient, as [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html).  If you do that, you get $1$.  I note that [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=BinomialCoefficient%5B1.5%2C0%5D) resolves it to $1$.

Comment: As for your "not sure what happens when $k=0$ here" in the case of falling factorial, the usual convention is that $\prod_{\emptyset} = 1$, i.e. the "empty product" is equal to the identity element of multiplication (similarly as the "empty sum" is zero - the identity element of addition). So $(x)_0 = 1$.

Comment: ${1.5\choose k}=(1.5)(.5)\dotsb(1.5-k+1)/k!$. When $k=0$, both numerator and denominator are empty products, and the empty product is $1$.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what the definition of $\binom nk$ is.

- If you define $\binom nk$ to be the number of $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set, then $\binom{1.5}0$ makes no sense.
- If you define $\binom{n}k=\frac{n!}{k!\cdot (n-k)!}$, then $\binom{1.5}0$ again makes no sense, because you cannot take the factorial of a non-integer.
- You can extend the factorial function using the Gamma function. If you define $\binom{n}k=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)}$, then it follows that $\binom{1.5}0=1$.
- It is common to generalize the definition of $\binom nk$ as follows. For any $k\in \{0,1,2,\dots\}$, and any $n\in \mathbb C$, we define
  $$
  \binom nk=\frac{n\cdot (n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)}{k!}=\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(n-i)}{k!}.
  $$
  This matches the combinatorial definition in all cases where the combinatorial definition makes sense. In this case, we see that
  $$
  \binom{1.5}0=\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{-1}(1.5-i)}{0!}=\frac11=1.
  $$
  To explain, note that $\prod_{i=0}^{-1}(1.5-i)$ is a product ranging over all numbers $i$ such that $0\le i\le -1$. This is an empty set. By convention, the [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) is one.

So, the answer is either undefined, or one.

Comment: Of course, if you define $n^k$ as the number of functions from a $k$-element set to an $n$-element set, then $1.5^0$ would _also_ be undefined.

Comment: hi Mike, what did you mean by $0 \leq i \leq -1$ ?